# Is it required to add @Singleton on top of a function using dagger hilt if the module scope is already singleton?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

In the below code, I have a module where I call `@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)`. So the scope of this module is the application scope or singleton scope))
If I'll provide something inside the module, do I need to annotate that function with `singleton` as well?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you have to annotate that function with singleton as well.

`@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)`
means that you may use singleton in your **@Provides** functions, without it you can't make your **@Provides** functions singleton. In hilt **@Provides** functions have no-scope by default so if you don't annotate your **@Provides** function with singleton, every time it will return new object.

you can easily test my answer with below code

```
var count = 0

class TestingClass() {
    init {
        count++
    }

    fun printCount() = println("count: $count")
}

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class TestModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton // without this count will increase every time you inject TestingClass
    fun provideTestClass(): TestingClass {
        return TestingClass()
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. I'm just curious about one thing from your answer. Without `SingletonComponent` I still can mark my functions as `@Singleton`. E.g. using `ActivityComponent` allows marking the functions as `@Singleton`. It compiles, but maybe it will through runtime exception. BTW, I guess it won't have any effect. Only if I will inject the same thing multiple times from the same activity, but it's hard to find such a case))

Comment: No you can't make @Singleton without Singleton Component, gradle build must give error.

Comment: You can check, it compiles fine. I've used `@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)`. Maybe they've changed something.

Comment: Maybe you are using old versions it gives error in my computer.

Comment: I'm using the last versions. Maybe something wrong with the IDE) I'll check it out.

Comment: Yeah there should be error like this : scoped with @dagger.hilt.android.scopes.ActivityScoped may not reference bindings with different scopes:

Comment: Is it possible to create memory leaks if you forget to add `@Singleton` but you've installed the dependency in the `SingletonComponent::class`?